# Lower Case Problem (unable to run script created on MACOS) MYSQL-Workbench Lower case.. tables do not exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having problem working on a database my friend gave me. He created it on MAC and seems like Linux (debian) is case sensitive. 
Any idea how to make workbench convert everything to non-capital?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

unix is case sensitive .. ..

You could try change  the `etc/mysql/my.cnf` or you debian/MAC dir for mysql config

accordinng to 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Underneath the [mysqld] section
add:

```
lower_case_table_names = 1 // or 0 or 2
```

Restart mysql